# create data json php

Tags: php, json, sqlsrv

i'm little bit confused how i create response data like this.

```
  [
  {
    "profile": "Profile 1",
    "kumpulan_spot": [
      {
         "urutan": "1",
        "id": "0415AA9E2D",
        "checkpoint": "3. OFFICE DEPAN LT. 2",
        "lokasi": "WARU",
        "waktu": "none",
        "status": "none",
        "kondisi": "none",
        "foto": "none"
      },
      {
         "urutan": "2",
        "id": "0415AAA007",
        "checkpoint": "4. OFFICE KRIAN LT.3 - R. MIS",
        "lokasi": "KRIAN",
        "waktu": "none",
        "status": "none",
        "kondisi": "none",
        "foto": "none"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "profile": "Profile 2",
    "kumpulan_spot": [
      {
        "urutan": "3",
        "id": "0415AAA01B",
        "checkpoint": "2. OFFICE DEPAN LT.1 - R. MARKETING",
        "lokasi": "KRIAN",
        "waktu": "none",
        "status": "none",
        "kondisi": "none",
        "foto": "none"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

but so far what i have been trying

```
$myparams['nik'] = $_POST['nik']; 

$procedure_params = array( 
array(&$myparams['nik']  , SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)

);
$sql = "EXEC SP_GETJADWAL @nik=?";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql,$procedure_params);

 if( !$stmt ) {
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$return_hasil=[];
$myArray = []; 
if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt)){ 
    do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $arrItem=[];         
        $detailItem=[];
        // $i=0;

        //  while($i==0){
            $arrItem["Profile"]="Profile ".$row['Profile']; 
            // $i=1;
            //  }
            $detailCheckPoint=[];   
            $detailCheckPoint["urutan"]=$row['Urutan'];         
            $detailCheckPoint["id"]=$row['check_point_id'];
            $detailCheckPoint["checkpoint"]=$row['check_point_name'];
            $detailCheckPoint["lokasi"]=$row['check_point_loc'];
            $detailCheckPoint["waktu"]="none";
            $detailCheckPoint["status"]="none";
            $detailCheckPoint["kondisi"]="none";
            $detailCheckPoint["foto"]="none";
            $detailItem[]=$detailCheckPoint;    
            $arrItem["ListCheckPoint"]=$detailItem;
            $return_hasil[]=$arrItem;


    }


    } while ( sqlsrv_next_result($stmt) );
     echo json_encode($return_hasil);
}else{
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
 }else{
     echo 'Connection Failure<br/>';
 }
```

and get result like this

```
[
  {
    "Profile": "Profile 1",
    "ListCheckPoint": [
      {
        "urutan": "1",
        "id": "0415AA9E2D",
        "checkpoint": "3. OFFICE DEPAN LT. 2",
        "lokasi": "WARU",
        "waktu": "none",
        "status": "none",
        "kondisi": "none",
        "foto": "none"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Profile": "Profile 1",
    "ListCheckPoint": [
      {
        "urutan": "2",
        "id": "0415AAA007",
        "checkpoint": "4. OFFICE KRIAN LT.3 - R. MIS",
        "lokasi": "KRIAN",
        "waktu": "none",
        "status": "none",
        "kondisi": "none",
        "foto": "none"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Profile": "Profile 1",
    "ListCheckPoint": [
      {
        "urutan": "3",
        "id": "0415AAA01B",
        "checkpoint": "2. OFFICE DEPAN LT.1 - R. MARKETING",
        "lokasi": "KRIAN",
        "waktu": "none",
        "status": "none",
        "kondisi": "none",
        "foto": "none"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

im new in creating data json and little bit confused how to achieve response what i want

Comment: what's the problem? The format looks correct.

Comment: you want to insert multiple array inside "kumpulan_spot". on what condition you're deciding to put element inside "kumpulan_spot" ?

Comment: @TouheedKhan on condition $arrItem["Profile"]="Profile ".$row['Profile']; sir so the Profile can have many kumpulan_spot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Code as per request :**

**Try this code :**

I hope it does work.

```
$arrItem["Profile"] ="Profile ".$row['Profile']; 
$detailCheckPoint=[];   
$detailCheckPoint["urutan"]=$row['Urutan'];         
$detailCheckPoint["id"]=$row['check_point_id'];
$detailCheckPoint["checkpoint"]=$row['check_point_name'];
$detailCheckPoint["lokasi"]=$row['check_point_loc'];
$detailCheckPoint["waktu"]="none";
$detailCheckPoint["status"]="none";
$detailCheckPoint["kondisi"]="none";
$detailCheckPoint["foto"]="none";
foreach ($return_hasil as $key1 => $value) {
    if($value["Profile"] === $arrItem["Profile"]) {
        var_dump($detailCheckPoint);
        $return_hasil[$key1]["ListCheckPoint"][] = $detailCheckPoint;
        continue 2;
    }
}
$arrItem['ListCheckPoint'] = array($detailCheckPoint);
$return_hasil[]=$arrItem;
```

Comment: its working thank you,  but there is 1 data cannot display to my json structure @Touheed Khan

Comment: @anasrachmadi what data ? please explain so that I can rectify issue.

Comment: so in my data there are profile 1 contain json array [1,2,3] and profile 2 contain [1,2]. with your code just display profile 1 [2,3] and profile 2 [2]. @Touheed Khan

Comment: [http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142045/create-data-json-php] join this chat for details

Answer (score 0):

Remove the initialization from the while loop

```
 $detailItem=[];
```

Comment: still not working, profile 1 missing and just display profile 2 with my all element

Comment: remove `detailCheckPoint=[]` from while

Comment: still not working, its look like its fetch last row data table so profile 1 not display @Nishant Nair